# wxPython app frozen during the execution

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm creating an application with python 2.7 and wxpython 2.8 that should execute a long loop (some hours) on a list of files.

I programmed a button that should interrupt the loop as I press it, but at the moment I start the application, it freezes and I can't interact in any way until the loop ends.
I also tried to add a small period of sleep with `time.sleep`, up to 1 second, which is really bad for the speed and doesn't resolve the issue.

Is there a way to run this loop "in the background", so that the user can still modify some parameters and more important stop the loop?

I can say about the loop that it doesn't require a lot of resources, it just requires a lot of time, so I don't understand why it freezes.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I'm not sure, right now the main application has more than 1000 lines and it'll be much longer when finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using threads in the standard solution for this type of problem.  The wxPython demo under Processes and Events | Threads has a working example of using threads.

There are a few issues when running threads from wxPython (and most other guis), so you might want to read the comments in the example, and maybe the wiki to understand what's going on, etc. In particular, wxPython needs to be run from the main thread, so do your file processing in a different thread, and then your file processing should communicate with the main thread using something like wx.PostEvent or wx.CallAfter.

Comment: I still have to fully understand how threads work, but it seems that you had the right idea. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good luck.  Basic threads in Python aren't too difficult, nor very powerful, but they are a good tool for this job (low resources but slow).  There are also tutorials around the web, and, of course, post again with followup questions if you have them.

Comment: Now it fully works, thanks a lot! To help people with the same problem, [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/) there is a useful tutorial. Just with the help of the first example I managed to run the application without any problem.